# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am playing around with ASP.NET MVC5 Identity and trying to implement claims based authentication.

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string subject, string type, string value>>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is the piece of code:

```
public ActionResult GetClaims()
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var claims = from c in identity.Claims
                 select new
                 {
                     subject = c.Subject.Name,
                     type = c.Type,
                     value = c.Value
                 };
    return claims;
}
```

I am following an example from http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/

Comment: What is it your method does - is it returning a view - i.e. it would need to be `return view(claims);` (although your creating an anonymous object so that wont work in a view) or are you returning json to an ajax call? Or is it just a method that you use somewhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is in a MVC controller you should return a view, which accepts `IEnumerable<Claim>` as model:

```
public ActionResult GetClaims()
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var claims = from c in identity.Claims
                 select new
                 {
                     subject = c.Subject.Name,
                     type = c.Type,
                     value = c.Value
                 };
    return View(claims);
}
```

If it is in a api controller you can return `IHttpActionResult`

```
public IHttpActionResult GetClaims()
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var claims = from c in identity.Claims
                 select new
                 {
                     subject = c.Subject.Name,
                     type = c.Type,
                     value = c.Value
                 };
    return Ok(claims);
}
```

Comment: And if going api route, returning `IEnumerable<ClaimView>` of a concrete class is also perfectly Ok

Comment: @jenson-button-event it wouldn't compile unless the concrete type implemented IHttpActionResult.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<ClaimView> GetClaims()` is what I meant. Perfectly acceptable web api method. Or `public IEnumerable<object> GetClaims()` if you want to return anonymous

Comment: @jenson-button-event I see what you meant. Yes that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things. You are try to return an enumerable of anonymous types as an `ActionResult`. Typically, ActionResults expect you to return a reference to a view (razor template) passing in the model:

```
return View(model);
```

If you want to just return data, then you need to return a `JsonResult`

```
return Json(new { Data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just returning data so the Json method worked.

Comment: anonymous types are fine when return a `JsonResult` (just not when returning a view)